# Pass variable to RegExp with word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to pass to RegExp value of variable and point a word boundary. I have a string to be checked if it contains a variable value. 
I don't know how to pass to regexp as a variable value and a word boundary attribute.

So something like this:

```
var sa="Sample";
var re=new RegExp(/\b/+sa);
alert(re.test("Sample text"));
```

I tried some ways to solve a problem but still can't do that :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this: `re = new RegExp("\\b" + sa)`

And as @RobW mentioned, you may need to escape the `sa`.

See this: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: `eval`? Ever heard of the `RegExp` constructor?

Comment: Don't forget to escape the user input (`sa`), unless it's intended that the input can also be a regular expression.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get ALL occurrences (`g`), be case insensitive (`i`), and use boundaries so that it isn't a word within another word (`\\b`):

```
re = new RegExp(`\\b${sa}\\b`, 'gi');
```

---

Example:

```
let inputString = "I'm John, or johnny, but I prefer john.";
let swap = "John";
let re = new RegExp(`\\b${swap}\\b`, 'gi');
console.log(inputString.replace(re, "Jack")); // I'm Jack, or johnny, but I prefer Jack.
```

Comment: Your answer is the closest thing to what I'm on the hunt for.  What is the quotes you're using, where is the documentation to pipe in variables with `${swap}`

Comment: @AlexanderDixon are you asking about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: `element_text.match(new RegExp(matching_option_text, 'gi'))`  I want to pass the "matching_option_text" variables with the `^$` start and end delimiter.

Comment: here is a better representation of what I'm asking. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52047817/5076162

Comment: I don't see `\\b${swap}\\b` working in my phpstorm editor - I just get a red underscore - is this actually javascript? Is there a pure javascript version of this?

Comment: @user1432181 It's regular JavaScript. See template literals link above.

Comment: My mistake - phpstorm was showing .php embedding Javascript; if I put the code into a pure js file then it works.